# JQuery Проверка на наличие участника в группе ВК

Tags: jquery

Нужна помощь!
Есть функция:

```
function getBonus() { 
if ($('#vkPage').val() == ''){ 
$('#error_bonus').show(); 
return $('#error_bonus').html('Введите страницу'); 
}
```

Есть так же следующие переменные:

```
$('#vkPage').val() - Человек
$settings->vk_group - Группа
$settings->vk_group_id - ID группы
$settings->vk_token - VK Token левой страницы
```

Необходимо в функцию добавить проверку, является ли Человек участником в Группе?
Я не думаю, что все вышеперечисленные переменные нужны для этого, но это всё, что я нашёл в sql, связанное с VK.
Собственно на выходе проверка должна выглядеть как-то так

```
Если пользователь $('#vkPage').val() состоит в группе $settings->vk_group, то
```

`...`

В старых скриптах было что-то подобное, но как бы это переделать под то, что я имею сейчас... Старый скрипт: https://pastebin.com/wJkN7Pkr

Comment: На каком языке программирования написан второй пример кода?

Comment: Он написан в файле .php, какой язык - без понятия

Comment: Если Вы про $settings->vk_group и прочее - то это переменные из sql берутся, как я понял